# How can I start a tor browser from the vidalia panel using the tor browser bundle?

Tags: linux, browser, tor

I have installed the tor browser bundle on a linux system. I start it from the command line by

:~$ ./.tor/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser

This will first launch vidalia and then open a preconfigured tor browser. If I close the browser, then vidalia is still running, but I don't know how to 'get back' the tor configured browser. Is there a hidden button on the vidalia panel or something that will get a browser running? I cannot find any.

What I do now, is to exit vidalia, and run the script again, thus reconnecting to the tor network and all. This is time consuming and seems unnecessary. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217092/restart-tor-browser-after-closing
Maybe there is no solution at the moment.